# How to open a different form depending on which user is currently logged in?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have 3 different forms: *frmLogin.vb* (this is where the user will start), *frmAdminPage.vb* (Admin form), *frmTeacherPage.vb* (Teacher form) and finally *frmStudentPage.vb* (Student form)

I am asked to design a `Spelling Bee system` for my coursework, but so far the teacher wants me to program how to open different forms depending on which user is logged in using a "database".

The database I'm using is Access 2007. It has the following fields: `ID` (autonumber), `Username` (text), `Password` (text), `UserAuthorization` (integer). I already have 3 different accounts to prepare for this;

**my accounts**

---

```
ID = 1, Username = Admin, Password = admin, UserAuthorization = 1

ID = 2, Username = Teacher, Password = teacher, UserAuthorization = 2

ID = 3, Username = Student, Password = student, UserAuthorization = 3
```

---

**my code**

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmLogin

Dim conn As New OleDbConnection

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    'Check if user has inputted no data
    If txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all fields.", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        'Connect to database
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SpellingBeeSystem.accdb"
    End If

    Try
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT Username, Password FROM UserAccount WHERE Username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND Password='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
        Dim sqlCom As New OleDbCommand(sql)

        sqlCom.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()

        Dim sqlRead As OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader

        If sqlRead.Read Then
            'Code to check which level of authorization the user is then select the appropriate form to show
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password.", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

            txtUsername.Text = ""
            txtPassword.Text = ""

            txtUsername.Focus()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to databse. System Error:" & ex.Message, "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

The comment that says `"Code to check which level of authorization the user is then select the appropriate form to show"`; I want to know how to code this part...

I need the program to check which level of authorization the user has and open a form depending on that level.

Thanks in advance!! Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: if you modify your sql to also select `UserAuthorization`, should be able to call `sqlRead.GetInt32(2)` (since it'll be the third field) to  get your `UserAuthorization` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly if this works, but it could work, so give it a try:

**Code**

```
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Data.OleDb

    Public Class frmLogin

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

        'Check if user has inputted no data
        If txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all fields.", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            'Connect to database
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SpellingBeeSystem.accdb"
Try
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT Username, Password, UserAuthorization  FROM UserAccount WHERE Username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND Password='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
            Dim sqlCom As New OleDbCommand(sql)

            sqlCom.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()

            Dim sqlRead As OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader

            If sqlRead.Read Then
                If sqlRead[2] == 1 Then
                    frmAdminPage.Show()
                ElseIf sqlRead[2] == 2 Then
                    frmTeacherPage.Show()
                ElseIf sqlRead[2] == 3 Then
                    frmStudentPage.Show()
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password.", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

                txtUsername.Text = ""
                txtPassword.Text = ""

                txtUsername.Focus()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to databse. System Error:" & ex.Message, "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
        End If
    End Sub
    End Class
```

**What I have done**

First edited the sql request `sql` to request the row `UserAuthorization` too.
Then check what the recived data contains - it should be 1, 2 or 3. Depending on what we recived open the form you wan't to and you're done.

I hope this works, if it doesn't check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for some more information how to use the `OleDbDataReader` class.

**Update**

You didn't aborted the request to the database wehn the user didn't typed anything, so the code for the request have to be in the else after the input check aswell.

Comment: Thanks, it actually works. However, for some odd reason, if the user does not type anything sometimes I get an error saying connectionstring property has not been initialized :(

Comment: Bear in mind that this code is wide open to Sql Injection attack.  You should use parameterized queries, especially when part of the query comes from user input.

Comment: Jup, `' OR '1=1' --` should already give access to the given account